# Camera isn't available - Trusted Face ( Android Lollipop - Nexus 5)

Tags: camera, nexus-5, 5.0-lollipop

Sometimes I've noticed that the Smart Lock - Trusted Face feature doesn't work, no matter what the lighting or the position of my face relative to the phone.

I thought that an "Improve face matching" should do the trick, but when I go to do that, I get this:

[image: Android Lollipop - Improve face matching]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>

Usually a restart fixes things, but this isn't a really good solution. The camera app works normally even when this happens. Has someone found a way to fix this somehow, or should I just wait for the next update from Google?

Comment: There is a possibility that there is an app that is still running and using the camera, and [hasn't released the resource](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html#TaskReleaseCamera) (resource leak). You probably need to check 3rd-party apps that use camera and make sure they are closed properly.

Comment: I thought of that, but since the Google camera app, Instagram etc. work normally, I don't think that's the case.

Comment: How did you upgrade to 5.0, through OTA? If yes, did you do it after a factory reset?

Comment: @VishnuPrasadKallummel Yes, through OTA. No, no factory reset just prior to updating, neither after.

Comment: Ok, I think a factory reset would do the trick, as I have 5.0.1 and the face unlock is working fine. By the way, how are you getting the battery percentage on the battery icon?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try a factory reset if there's no other answer by someone else. As per the battery percentage, I used http://forum.xda-developers.com/google-nexus-5/themes-apps/app-enable-battery-percentage-android-4-t2516913

Comment: I'm also sometimes affected by this issue. When it starts, the camera app works normally until I switch it to the front-facing camera. After that it crashes and I cannot use it any more. only workaround is to restart.
Did you try the factory reset? I'd prefer not do that…
Nexus 5 with Android 5.0.1 installed through OTA.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is an issue with the Smart Lock app itself. When I enabled the face unlock I started getting this error. The camera ceases to work after some time, when I notice that the smart lock icon just blinks on the lock screen (which shows a failed attempt to access camera). Then neither the camera app works nor can I access the camera via Smart Lock settings. I started having this issue whenever I enabled face recognition and I stopped having this issue altogether when I disabled the said feature.

It's a shame that despite being an extremely efficient and fast feature, this causes such a problem that it needs to be disabled.