# Front camera not working after a while, issue with Smart Lock

Tags: nexus-5, 6.0-marshmallow, front-camera, smart-lock

This is basically the same issue as described here:

[Camera isn't available - Trusted Face ( Android Lollipop - Nexus 5)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/89818/camera-isnt-available-trusted-face-android-lollipop-nexus-5)

Im running Marshmallow on a Nexus 5.

So yesterday i enabled password protection and Smart Lock with "Trusted Face".
This worked great so far.

However, **after some time (like 4-8 hours) the front camera will stop working.**
This will cause Smart Lock to not recognize me obviuosly and i have to use my password every time.

When launching the camera app, i am able to use the back camera, however **switching to front only gives me a black screen** and the app does not react to input anymore.

**Rebooting the device will fix this,** until it starts againt after the mentioned time-span.

Anyone got any ideas?

EDIT:
Clearing the cache (as advised in an answer) did **prolong the time the front camera worked to about 36 hours but did not fix this permanently.**

Comment: I had issues with my nexus 5 front camera not working randomly (switching to front camera would give a blank screen). wiping cache fixed it. I suggest you try it.

Comment: I just rebooted and wiped my cache. Works now obv. Will keep you updated.

Comment: @awadheshv consider posting that as an answer since it also helped OP (and yourself :)

Comment: I had this problem too. Extremely annoying!

Answer (score 1):

I had issues with my nexus 5 front camera not working randomly (switching to front camera would give a blank screen). wiping cache fixed it. I suggest you try it.

Comment: You already posted this as a comment.

Comment: @AaronGillion yeah he did, however it was suggested to post as an answer, as **this was actually what fixed this** (to my surprise) as my smart lock still works (running since yesterday).

Comment: Unfortunately the "error" or misbehaviour of the front camera came back yesterday evening. So clearing the cache did make it work longer, but is **not a permanent fix.**